# How to use top margin perfectly?

Tags: html, css, margin

```css
#container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

The two element should have margin, but there is no any margin. How margin could be placed between them

Comment: Your question isn't clear

Answer (score -1):

Set `display` to `table` on the container.

```css
#container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display:table;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```